# views order change when ad loads

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

Im working on a simple crosswords application,the main layout is this
http://imageshack.us/a/img802/6618/9v8c.png
a fragment at the top the load ads so ads be present on any application page , the below fragment have a linearlayout for the crossword table, under it 2 linearlayouts , one for hints and the other for keyboard and all the 3 linearlayouts under a linearlayout with vertical orientation

okay now when ad refresh or when i press the power button and power on to resume app again , (and on some devices when filling any of the table squares)
this happen
http://imageshack.us/a/img818/5125/lk8v.png
the crosswords linearlayout comes below other 2 layouts as shown and also the squares inside the lnearlayout gets randomized, i load the crosswords iems in an asynktask on the oncreateview method of the fragment
so my question is any1 know where to look at that makes this mess, i even tried a tablelayout and still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mess on view orders was caused by calling view.bringToFront();
i was calling it before animating every square, took it off and eveery